# Time-Out Error handling in Ionic Application - Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic2

My Ionic Application has multiple pages. Sometimes, there is a server side error and my application stops with loader screen for minutes together. How to Handle server timeout error? I also want to notify the user that there is a error and have a button to reload the page or the entire application!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a good and valid question. Do not down vote without any reason. If any please comment

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch the HTTP request timeout error, RXjs provides timeoutWith operator, which will emit observable error if HTTP request is idle for particular milli second.

**Sample Code:**

```
return this.httpClient.request<Response>(method, url, request).pipe(
      timeoutWith(10000, observableThrowError(new Error('Http Timeout exceeds'))),
      map((response: any) => ({ // handle success }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => => ({ // handle error })
    );
```